# Cassandra nodetool flush not working, returns SyntaxException

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to learn Caasandra using this example:

http://abiasforaction.net/cassandra-query-language-cql-tutorial/

But when I do :

```
nodetool flush animals;
```

I get:

```
cqlsh:animals> nodetool flush animals;
SyntaxException: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'nodetool' ([nodetool].
..)
```

And no SSTable is created in the 'data' directory:

```
C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\data\animals\monkeys-869abe807e2811e8b317031f29d835e7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Victor, issue the command `nodetool flush animals` from the operating system command line, not within cqlsh. Nodetool is a Cassandra tool, not a CQL command.